# Grub 2 doesnot show any OS.

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi, elementary

I am using Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series that originally came with ubuntu. I changed it to windows completely according to my needs. Today I tried dual booting with Elementary OS Luna. I installed it but the windows bootloader kept on reappearing. So I installed EasyBCD and exported a backup and tried to edit the entires. After restarting, grub was loading but it is like waiting for commands with no OS list or anything. So I type in Reboot and go to boot options and select the harddisk in the legacy options and I can get into the elementary OS. How do I fix this?

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so ElementaryOS is off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**
W

Answer (score 0):

Boot into a live CD and try this Ubuntu option instead of the easyBCD one in windows.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I've had similar issues.

Comment: I tried it with the elementary OS Live USB but there seems to be some Xauthorization problems. I think that the easyBCD might be creating the problem but I don't know. I also tried reinstalling the elementary OS but it is having no effect.